# I get WordPress database error: [Incorrect table name ''] SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `` from

Tags: php, wordpress

hello every one i am new to wordpress i am trying to get data from my table in a template but i get
**"WordPress database error: [Incorrect table name '']
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM ``"** in return, this is my code in php

```
<?php /* Template Name: verifypayment */ 
  if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    wp_redirect(wp_login_url());
    exit;
  }
  $user_id = get_current_user_id();

  global $wpdb;

  $payments = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT txn_code, amount, paid_at FROM wp_paystack_forms_payments WHERE user_id = $user_id And paid = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");

  $lastpayment = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT txn_code, amount, paid_at, settled FROM wp_fm_verify_page WHERE userid = $user_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");


  $dt = new DateTime($payments[0]->paid_at);
  $getdate = $dt->format('Y-m-d');
  $gethour = $dt->format('Y-m-d');

  if ($getdate = date('Y-m-d')) {
    if($wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix.'fm_verify_page', array("userid" => $user_id, "txn_code" => $payments[0]->txn_code, "amount" => $payments[0]->amount, "settled" => "Y", "email" => $payments[0]->amount, "paid" => $payments[0]->paid, "paid_at" => $payments[0]->paid_at), array("%d", "%s", "%d", "%s", "%s", "%d", "%d"))){
        echo 'successfully inserted';
    }
  }
```

that the php code

Comment: Are you sure those are the correct table names you are using?

Comment: well i guess this "$wpdb->fm_verify_page" is equal to wp_fm_verify_page so it is @John

Comment: It might not be.  It could have a different prefix like wp8_fm_verify_page.  Do you have phpmyadmin and can check?

Comment: well it starts with wp_ @john i have checked the database

Comment: well my table name in insert function is not in quotes so it does not sees it as a string, it works now. thanks anyway @john